# Cannot access module "android.app.Activity" which is a superclass of "com.example.myapp"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on a personal Android Project. I have worked on it quite a lot and now after I reopen the project after a while I get red squiggly all over the source code of my Activities and the error says:

> Cannot access module "android.app.Activity" which is a superclass
> of "com.example.myapp". Check your module classpath for missing or
> conflicting dependencies

What should I do? I am kinda new to android development, and I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, did you try to do a clean and then build?

Comment: @César Bermúdez how do you do that?